# Is this a portmanteau, contraction, or perhaps both?

Tags: orthography, contractions, portmanteau-words

**I have chosen to edit this post because it apparently has offended some of the more sensitive among us.**  While, personally, I feel this should prompt discourse rather than down votes, I do not wish to offend people who unwittingly stumble upon this question.

I was contemplating a word that is a contraction of two words.  [Click here if you wish to know the word in question - but be warned it is mildly offensive to some.](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/fucktarded).  (Try as I might, I cannot think of a non-vulgar example that blurs the line so effectively.  See further for details.)

This word does not use an apostrophe to denote its contraction.  Rather it has borrowed the morphology of half of each word to make a new whole.  The new whole, however, has a bit of synergy that the words themselves convey but perhaps not to the same degree.  (Thanks to Bradd Szonye for helping me phrase that properly.)

Is this strictly a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) as is suggested in the linked definition above?

My question is:  Would a word like this be considered a portmanteau or a contraction?  Or perhaps both?

Does the synergy of meaning make it a portmanteau, or does the ability of both words standing alone to convey similar meaning make it a mere contraction?

Comment: That is your favorite neologism?

Comment: @medica #1, I said one of.  #2, *De gustibus non est disputandum*.

Comment: Apostrophes are not necessary for contraction; apostrophes are silent. Contractions are done to save syllables in speech; how they get represented in English spelling, which neither indicates syllables nor represents speech, is something of a creative endeavor. Contractions are often spelled with apostrophes, but that doesn't hafta be the case.

Comment: @JohnLawler So, you'd say that hafta is a contraction, and not a portmanteau due to their connection in normal speech?

Comment: If you wanna give it a name, _contraction_ seems as good as any other. What would you call it?

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree with that.  As I've said above, I'm just confused where contraction ends and portmanteau begins … or if there is no overlap as one is orthography and one is semantic …

Comment: They were coined to describe different phenomena; they're not part of a consistent category system.

Comment: Why this question offends anyone so much that they had decided to downvote it, beats me.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I have revised out of peer pressure. But, I agree with you. People have begun to down vote for emotional reasons, and not on the merit of the question itself.

Comment: To be honest, for the purposes of the present "discussion", I can't see any real difference between *fucktarded, fuckwit,* and *dimwit*. Except that the first is pretty much unknown, and the last isn't particularly offensive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The first has quite a following in the US.  But, the difference is that dim wit vs. dimwit is just a deletion of the space between the words, I don't know that it would be anything more than a contraction.

Comment: Gimmie a break! - ***nitwit***, then!

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, would you call nitwit a portmanteau or a contraction?

Comment: Just so you know, I did not downvote this. Which means this comment is an indicator of how damaging downvoting with a comment *is*.

Comment: @medica Do you mean with or without a comment?  (And, I liked you better as Susan!  It seemed more personal, somehow ;-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia article linked in your question has a discussion of this point:

> This definition overlaps with the grammatical term contraction, but a distinction can be made between a portmanteau and a contraction by noting that contractions are formed from words that would otherwise appear together in sequence, such as do and not, whereas a portmanteau word is formed by combining two or more existing words that all relate to a singular concept which the portmanteau describes.

Thus, a portmanteau is a kind of contraction, but it has features that other contractions do not: It combines grammatically unrelated words to create a new semantic concept, whereas a typical contraction is simply a convenience of pronunciation.

Note that this is a common distinction but not a defining one. The defining trait of a portmanteau is simply that it combines distinct morphemes into a new morpheme with blended phonetic and semantic elements. The whole is more than the sum of its parts, unlike a contraction like *didn’t* that simply means *did not.* Portmanteaus also allow you to combine grammatically diverse words, but some (like *fucktard*) don't need to.

Comment: Heh I've done that too. Sometimes you just need to have it pointed out or restated in slightly different words. Like my singing accent question.

Comment: It's both. You have a new morpheme created from a blend of two others, phonetically and semantically.

Comment: As smog is both smoke and fog, a fucktard is both outrageous (fucking) and stupid (retarded), but the whole is greater than the sum of its parts. The distinction that Wikipedia notes is sufficient but not necessary to spot a portmanteau. The key is that there's a synergistic blend of sound and meaning.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the "sufficient but not necessary" commentary. Trying to think of another portmanteau to illustrate the point, because I too would prefer to avoid repeating the example.

Comment: @braddszonye I may redraft this question with a more benign example word. Because, I think people's opinions are being colored by their "outrage" at my word choice.

Comment: Also, *sumbitch* = *son of a bitch* might provide a useful contrast, because I would **not** consider that a portmanteau. *Fucktard* is different because it has a shade of meaning that *fucking retard* does not, but I'm having trouble expressing how.

Comment: On further thought, I think *fucktard* may actually be a portmanteau of *fuck-up,* not *fucking.* Because that's exactly the shade of meaning I was thinking of – just put my finger on it.

Comment: Revised, see above.